# RPM + error when I build rpm file

Tags: linux

please advice why I get the error "error: License field must be present in package: (main package)"

I need to create rpm file ,

I only have the spec file under SPECS

and the test.sh script under SOURCES

what’s wrong here?

```
 [root@linux /usr/src/redhat]# ls

 BUILD  RPMS  SOURCES  SPECS  SRPMS
```

the spec file:

```
Summary: An example tool. To show a simple rpm build of the tool.
Name: test.sh
Version: 6.2
Release: 2
Source:/root/test.sh
Group: Development/Debuggers
BuildRoot:/var/tmp/test.sh
%description

 #  rpm -ba my_spec.spec
 error: License field must be present in package: (main package)
 # ls ../SOURCES/
   test.sh
```

Comment: By the looks of it I've solved your initial question. However as you've found, you've run into a new problem. I'm afraid writing spec files is a lot more complicated than the example you've provided, but perfectly doable. I've yet to find a decent example of packaging a simple bash script but [something like this fedora guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackageMaintainers/CreatingPackageHowTo) is better than nothing. Just strip out the build commands & requirements.

Comment: but I have linux red-hat not fedora , second can you please give the correct spec file?

Comment: Both RHEL and Fedora use the same rpm technology and the tutorial is valid. (That doesn't mean you can install fedora rpms in redhat or vica verca!) [This forum thread here (see post 3)](http://forum.unity-linux.org/archive/index.php/thread-1218.html) is an example of packaging a bash script but I haven't tried or checked it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wild shot in the dark... have you tried adding something like:

```
License: OtherLicense
```

before `%description`?

Comment: OK I add this but now I get: error: Bad file: /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/test.sh: No such file or directory


RPM build errors:
    Bad file: /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/test.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: Awesome, looks like that's solved the problem you're asking about originally, going to add a further comment to your question.